# The effectiveness of Tongkat Ali in curing Erectile Dysfunction

Tags: supplement, testosterone, erectile-dysfunction, traditional-medicine, libido

Tongkat Ali (EURYCOMA LONGIFOLIA) is a well-known supplement (especially) in Southeast Asia region, mainly by man to improve his sexual performance and desire.

Tongkat Ali is a kind of traditional medicine, which means that it is not rigorously tested on clinical side. So one would naturally be skeptical about the whatever magical claims Tongkat Ali sellers try to sell us.

My questions:

1. From my 5 minute Google search, [Tongkat Ali is quite helpful in raising testosterone and libido level](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3669033/). But is this study conclusive? Is it a "proven" fact that Tongkat can really raise testosterone and libido level?
2. What about Erectile Dysfunction? Is there any evidence that apart from boosting testosterone level, Tongkat Ali can also help to combat Erectile Dysfunction, and one can use as it a replacement for Viagra/Cialis over the long term?